# XML Schema validation does not validate

Tags: xml, validation, schema

I am trying to validate an xml file against a schema using VB.net. My problem is, files that do not match the schema at all still pass with no errors. Here's the code I'm using:

```
   Private Sub ValidateDelete(oStream As Stream, sExt As String)
        _DeleteErrorMessage = ""
        Dim XmlFileDoc As New XmlDocument
        Dim oSettings As XmlReaderSettings = New XmlReaderSettings()

        Dim scSet As New XmlSchemaSet
        Dim sSchemapath As String = AppSettings("DeleteSchemaFile")

        Using scRead As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(New FileStream(sSchemapath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), Nothing, sSchemapath)
            scSet.Add(XmlSchema.Read(scRead, Nothing))

        End Using

        scSet.CompilationSettings = New XmlSchemaCompilationSettings
        scSet.Compile()

        oSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema
        oSettings.Schemas = scSet

        AddHandler oSettings.ValidationEventHandler, New ValidationEventHandler(AddressOf ValidationEventHandler)

        Dim oreader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(oStream, oSettings)

        Try
            XmlFileDoc.Load(oreader)

        Catch xex As XmlException
            _DeleteErrorMessage = xex.Message
            ValidXML = False

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        Finally
            oreader.Close()
        End Try


    End Sub
    Private Sub ValidationEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ValidationEventArgs)

        If e.Severity = XmlSeverityType.Error Then
            _DeleteErrorMessage = e.Message
        End If

    End Sub
```

And here is the xsd file I'm validating against. As you can see, it is pretty simple.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xs:element name="patientlist">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="patient" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="hcoid" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
              <xs:element name="vendor-tracking-id">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:minLength value="1"></xs:minLength>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>

              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="report-year" >
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:length value="4"></xs:length>
                    <xs:pattern value="[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"></xs:pattern>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>

              <xs:element name="report-quarter">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:length value="1"></xs:length>
                    <xs:pattern value="[1-4]"></xs:pattern>
                  </xs:restriction>

                </xs:simpleType>

              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The file allows customers to delete records from our system. If I validate a delete file that is missing elements or has invalid values, it works fine and I get the expected error messages. If I validate a file that is not a delete file, I get no error messages. It passes without a problem.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: It helps to say what programming language you are using. This looks like Visual Basic to me. You don't want every reader to have to work that out for themselves.

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention this is VB.net.